# AMPScript : A Data Extension of this name does not exist

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions

I want to retrieve informations in a Data Extension synchronised with an event (object) on a preprod environnement to make custom fields on an email :[image]
and my targets for the email are like this :

[image]

I want to retrieve the sessions that have an eventName equals to WomensForum
So I have this code with a lookupOrderRows

```
%%[
VAR @idevent, @sessions, @nbsessions, 
@rows,@row,@nbrow

SET @eventName = attributevalue("MC_EventName")
SET @nbrow = 50
SET @sessions = lookupOrderedRows("EventApi__Schedule_Item__c",50,"EventApi__Start_Date__c",@eventName, "WOMEN'S FORUM SINGAPORE 2018","EventApi__Is_Active__c", "TRUE", "FormatType__c", "Workshop")
SET @nbsessions = rowcount(@sessions)
]%%
```

But I get this error :

> The Data Extension name for a LookupOrderedRows function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist.
>    Data Extension Name: EventApi__Schedule_Item__c
>    Function Call: lookupOrderedRows("EventApi__Schedule_Item__c",50,"EventApi__Start_Date__c",@eventName, "WOMEN'S FORUM SINGAPORE 2018","EventApi__Is_Active__c", "TRUE", "FormatType__c", "Workshop")
>    Parameter Name: DataExtensionName
>    Parameter Ordinal: 1

which I don't understand because if I understood correctly, my dataExtension should exist thanks to the API name. If you have any thought on this, don't hesitate. Thanks !

EDIT: example fields

[image]

Comment: Are you running this from a child business unit or from the parent business unit? Try looking up ent.EventApi__schedule_item__c also, if I understand your screenshot correctly, the name of your data extension is called Session (?) So try looking up on that

Comment: I'm on the good Business Unit but I don't have a real Data Extension in marketing cloud named "Session" because it is a custom object from lightning with many custom fields that I want to use in my email. I added a sample of fields in the image. Maybe I didn't understand how ampScript works but we should be able to use those custom object, don't we ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to use the [RetrieveSalesforceObject function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) instead of lookup, to call custom objects and it works perfectly.